# Puppet cyclical dependency issue due to conditional

Tags: puppet

I have a puppet module to manage firewalld, including creating the `/etc/firewalld` dir and adding custom services xml files to `/etc/firewalld/services`.

The dependency ordering for `enabled="true"` is

```
Package["$package_name"] -> File['/etc/firewalld'] -> Service["$service_name"]
```

and then on the service add function I have

```
define firewalld_zone_add_service($zone, $service) {
  exec { "firewalld_${zone}_add_service_${service}":
    path    => '/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin',
    command => "firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=${zone} --add-service=${service}",
    unless  => "firewall-cmd -q --permanent --zone=${zone} --query-service=${service}",
    notify  => Exec['firewalld_reload'],
    require => [Exec["firewalld_zone_create_$zone"],
                File['/etc/firewalld'],
                File['/etc/firewalld/services/networker.xml'],
                File['/etc/firewalld/services/snmpd.xml'],
               ]
  }
}
```

This all works fine, but when I set it to `enabled="false"` and set the ordering like this

```
Service["$service_name"] ->  File['networker'] -> File['snmpd'] -> File['/etc/firewalld'] -> Package["$package_name"]
```

I get a dependency cycle error. Without that ordering, it deletes the directory (and its contents) first and I get an error saying `unable to set $file_ensure on file` as it doesn't exist.

So my questions is, how do I manage this loop or set `$file_ensure` for `enabled="false"` to be null so it doesn't try and set anything if the directory removal also removes the managed configuration files.

I've tried setting `$file_ensure = undef`, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thank you.

Comment: can you use the --graph option of the puppet to generate the dependency graph and analyze the dependency cycle error?

Comment: --graph option will generate a cycles.dot file which can be viewed online at http://www.webgraphviz.com/

Comment: We can likely help you sort this out, but to do so we rely on a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  Additionally, we will need to see Puppet's error message detailing the cycle ("there is a cycle" is not nearly specific enough).